# kali linux vmware gcc not found error

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, vmware

I am new to kali linux and I try to find my way around it.. I have managed to install vmware workstation 12.1.1 but when I try to run it I get this error

> A compatible version of gcc was not found. GNU C Compiler (gcc) version 5.4.0 was not found

I have the gcc 6.1.1 installed and spent 3 days trying to fix this with no result.. Any help?

Comment: Where exactly does that message come from?

Comment: Kali linux is for penetration testing, it is not a general purpose GNU/Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I added another answer, that procedure worked for me.

Try running this:

```
sudo aptitude install gcc-4.3 make linux-headers-`uname -r` -y
```

and

```
sudo aptitude install libglib2.0-0
```

Did you fix it before i could respond? If you did, how did you?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310637/vmware-kernel-module-a-compatible-version-of-gcc-was-not-found).

> Upgrade Kali to the Latest Which is 4.8.0-kali1-amd64

```
apt upgrade

cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar xf vmmon.tar
tar xf vmnet.tar
cd vmmon-only
make
cd ../vmnet
make
cd ..
mkdir /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc
cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko
cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko
depmod -a
/etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

> I'm also hope that its will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Remove gcc and add if you don't have the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
```

Then:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-update
```

Now install gcc-5

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5
```

And the headers.
But remember: linux-headers-(Put here the output of `uname -r`)

```
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-4.8.0-kali2-amd64
```

Comment: this also not workable, coz linux-headers and gcc-5 already installed, bu default version used 6.2.1