# a compatible gcc 6.4.0 was not found

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

i have currently installed Kali Linux 2017.2, i also installed VMware but all i get after launching it is an error  "a compatible gcc 6.4.0 was not found"

i have tried apt-get update && apt-get upgrade.and ths [kali linux vmware gcc not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711261/kali-linux-vmware-gcc-not-found-error) 
i also tried to download a gcc debian package but actually i got ver6.3.0 yet my machine wants 6.4.0 so i am stuck don't know what to do

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See "What topics can I ask about here" in the [help/on-topic]. Perhaps [su] or [unix.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: but it is about the linux kernel

Comment: just do me a favour post my question i rely need a solution im real damn stuck

Comment: Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. I suggest you take the [Tour] and then read the [ask] page, especially the on-topic section here: [help/on-topic].